# The proper way to await databound property getters c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, async-await

What would be the most correct way to use async method in **databound** property getter? I am talking about solid, scientific arguments, not personal preferences. I've read many threads about the problem, but not this specific case. Some of the solutions don't work in all the cases, and some of the suggestion, well... they were just too subjective or just wrong.

**What I don't accept and why:**

- *You can't* - Actually, it is possible. There are many posts like "there are no such things like async properties", "it is against the design of the language" etc. but also there are many sensible explanations why such expressions are false
- *This should me method, not property* - It can't be. I want to databind it. I provide property "proxies" for people using this code because in the future there may be different method to calculate this pseudo-property. And I want the View-side of the binding to be simple as possible
- *Use property to store the cached result of the method* - that would defeat the purpose, it is actually something that changes dynamically and the class is an ORM Entity so it would store redundant data to the DB.
- *Use* `SomeTask.Result;` *or* `SomeTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - In most cases I would just use it. I've successfully used those in many cases i.e. Console applications. It's nice, clear and easily readable. But when I use it in databound property I get a deadlock

**Problem background (simplified)**

Let's say that I am responsible for developing ORM mechanism in a project. There was a first stable version, but now I want to add some properties to the `Entities` for the DataBinders who are responsible for the layout. I can edit `Entity` layer, but I can't edit `Mapping` and `Repository` layers. (I am not held againt my will, this situation is fictional simplification). All the methods in repositories are async. All I can do is ask someone responsible to provide identical synchronous methods for **all of the methods**, but it would be stupid to this kind of redundant work.

**Only solution I can use now**

```
_something = Task.Run(async () => await AnotherRepository.CalculateStuff(this)).Result;
```

And it just doesn't look right to me. It works, but I have to await my method inside the lambda in `Task.Run()`. I am stuck with it for the time being, and I want to know the simplest and correct approach.

**Repository method pseudo-code**

```
public async static Task<IList<CalculatedStuff>> CalculateStuff(SomeClass class)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var session = Helper.OpenSession())
            return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(CalculatedStuff)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("SomeClass", class))
                ///...
                .List<CalculatedStuff>();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you have a locking issue with the data?  You may need to use a semaphore like WaitOne to lock data so two processes don't try to access the same resource simultaneously.

Comment: No. I can call the property from any other piece of code. It only hangs when the property is databound as stated in my question.

Comment: When called from other piece of code it is running synchronously (blocked) so other thread can't access the data.  With async you have multiple threads which can cause conflicts.

Comment: You clearly have no idea what you are talking about. Please read my question. I am not having locking issue. In fact, there is no data I am accessing simultaneously.

Comment: To clarify, you want to call your async method synchronously from your getter, right? So that every access to that property caused request to your repository and blocked during that?

Comment: Yes. I want to access it every time, and yes it blocks but only when the property is called by the WPF databinding itself. It is all about the asynchronous context that is unavailable while binding (?in the binding thread? I don't really know the low level code behind the binding execution)

Comment: Also, what may be helpful. At first I though there was some exception that was raised, but calling the property from code behind ruled that out for me. The UI thread freezes and then when I break the debugger I am on the getter line. Also the solution I included in the question works. I just feel it's dirty.

Comment: With your solution above it will block every time, not just from binding (by blocks I mean the caller will wait for result until it can continue, not just UI blocking and not deadlock). So if your CalculateStuff takes 10 seconds, with your solution UI would freeze for 10 seconds when getter is executed, is that ok for you?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. Sorry for the misuse of the "block". Blocking is OK, my solution is the only one I found that doesn't cause deadlock

Comment: And you do not own the code of AnotherRepository.CalculateStuff method? Because if you properly implement it (by using ConfigureAwait(false) on every async call) - you would be able to just call AnotherRepository.CalculateStuff().Result at your property and it won't deadlock. Well of course doing blocking stuff in properties bound to UI is bad practice anyway but I'll just assume you know what you are doing and won't bother you with that.

Comment: I can tell someone how to reimplement it. Could you tell me how to properly implement the ConfigureAwait(false) in the code? I've updated the question with repository pseudocode. I am well aware that it is bad practice and it won't be implemented in the final version or someone will get fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the source code of `AnotherRepository.CalculateStuff`, you can implement it in a way that won't deadlock when called from bound property. First short summary of why it deadlocks. When you await something, current synchronization context is remembered and the rest of the method (after async) is executed on that context. For UI applications that means the rest of the method is executed on UI thread. But in your case UI thread is already blocked by waiting for the `Result` of task - hence deadlock.

But there is method of `Task` named `ConfigureAwait`. If you pass `false` for it's only argument (named `continueOnCapturedContext`) and await task returned by this method - it won't continue on captured context, which will solve your problem. So suppose you have:

```
 // this is UI bound
 public string Data
 {
     get { return GetData().Result; }
 }

 static async Task<string> GetData() {
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
     });
     return "test!";
 }
```

This will deadlock when called from UI thread. But if you change it:

```
 static async Task<string> GetData() {
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
     }).ConfigureAwait(false);
     return "test!";
 }
```

It won't any more.

For those who might read this later - don't do it this way, only if for temporary debugging purposes. Instead return dummy object from your property getter with some IsLoading flag set to true, and meanwhile load data in background and fill dummy object properties when done. This will not freeze your UI during long blocking operation.

Comment: Tested on sample code I've made for testing and works like charm so I believe it will work in this temporary version of an application.

Answer (score 2):

> there are no such things like async properties

I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) and [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) on "async properties" for data binding. I do take the stance that they are not *natural*, which is based on these (objective) observations:

- Properties read by data binding must return immediately (synchronously).
- Asynchronous operations are asynchronous (that is, they complete after some time).

Clearly, these are at complete odds with one another.

Now, there are a few different solutions, but any solution that attempts to violate one of these observations is going to be dubious, at best.

For example, you can attempt to violate the second observation by trying to run the asynchronous operation synchronously. As you discovered, [`Result` / `Wait` / `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (for reasons described in detail on my blog). `Task.Run(() => ...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will avoid the deadlock but will execute the code in a free-threaded context (which is OK for most code but *not all*). These are two different kinds of sync-over-async; I call them the "Blocking Hack" and the "Thread Pool Hack" in my [Async Brownfield article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx), which also covers two other kinds of sync-over-async patterns.

Unfortunately, there is no solution for sync-over-async that works in *every* scenario. Even if you get it to work, your users would get a substandard experience (blocking the UI thread for an indefinite amount of time), and you may have problems with app stores (I believe MS's at least will actively check for blocking the UI thread and auto-reject). IMO, sync-over-async is best avoided.

However, we obviously cannot violate the first observation, either. If we're data binding to the result of some asynchronous operation, we can't very well return it before the operation completes!

Or can we?

What if we change what the data binding is attaching to? Say, introduce a property that has a default value *before* the operation is completed, and changes (via `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to the result of the operation when the operation completes. That sounds reasonable... And we can stick in another property to indicate to the UI that the operation is in progress! And maybe another one to indicate if the operation failed...

This is the line of thinking that resulted in my [`NotifyTaskCompletion` type in the article on data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) (updated `NotifyTask` type [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs)). It is essentially a data-bindable wrapper for `Task<T>`, so the UI can respond dynamically to the asynchronous operation without trying to force it to be synchronous.

This *does* require some changes to the bindings, but you get a nice side effect that your UX is better (non-blocking).

> This should me method, not property

Well, you *can* do this as a property:

```
TEntity Entity { get { return NotifyTask.Create(() => Repository.GetEntityAsync()); } }
// Data bind to Entity.Result for the results.
// Data bind to Entity.IsNotCompleted for a busy spinner.
```

However, I would say that it's surprising behavior to have a property read kick off something significant like a database query or HTTP download. That's a pretty wide definition of "property". IMO, this would be better represented as a *method*, which connotates action more than a *property* does (or perhaps as part of an [asynchronous initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html), which I also describe on my blog). Put another way: I prefer my properties without side effects. Reading a property more than once and having it return different values is counterintuitive. This final paragraph is entirely my own opinion. :)

Comment: Thank you for you valuable input. I've read both blog post and msdn article and I agree with you. I was asking about a hack (you described two of them) and the one that @Evk provided is the most elegant for the time being. This was something I needed only at this development stage. FYI, so you can sleep at night knowing you did no harm: there is a lot of lazy loading in the project and the async call is invoked only once, but we needed it to test something. In the final version there will be a collection of entities with fully loaded subcollections.